# Nested loop in excel macro/VBA not resetting

Tags: excel, vba

As you will be able to tell by my code I am very new to excel/macros and hopefully it will be really simple for someone to help me out. Any help would be appreciated.
I have about 80 sheets in an Excel workbook. Each sheet has up to 10 columns that I am combining into one long column (column A). Then adding some new column headings into the now blank rows (B onwards).

The script works fantastically on the active sheet (even though I think I am asking it to do the sheet number not the active sheet). And the section that adds new headings cycles through all of the pages like I wanted. However the loop that does the combining of columns never runs on anything more than the active sheet, and no matter what I do I can't get it to do the same thing to all sheets.

Sorry for the stupid question!

```vb
Sub MoveIt()
    Dim LastRow As Long Dim sheetnum As Long
    sheetnum = 1
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        'I think this is checking of there is anything in column B and runs while there's still data. This doesn't seem to reset on the next sheet though?
        
        Do While (Worksheets(sheetnum).Range("B1").Value <> "")
            LastRow = Worksheets(sheetnum).Range("A" & Worksheets(sheetnum).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Worksheets(sheetnum).Range("B1:B" & Worksheets(sheetnum).Range("B" & Worksheets(sheetnum).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
            Worksheets(sheetnum).Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial
            Worksheets(sheetnum).Range("B1").EntireColumn.Delete xlToLeft
        'This finishes moving the data and then deletes the contents of column B, then moves column C to the left and repeats
        Loop
    
        Worksheets(sheetnum).Range("B1").Value = "column 2 heading"
        Worksheets(sheetnum).Range("C1").Value = "column 3 heading"
        Worksheets(sheetnum).Range("D1").Value = "column 4 heading"
        
        sheetnum = sheetnum + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

The main loop runs on each sheet in the workbook as expected and adds column headings. However the loop to check column data and move it only runs on the first (active) worksheet.

Comment: Remove the `sheetnum` variable. Everywhere in the code, replace `Worksheets(sheetnum)` with `ws`.

Comment: Hi, Have just tried this, it certainly makes the code a lot cleaner thank you! Unfortunately it still does the same thing, that loop to combine columns only runs on the active sheet. However the headings are added to all of the sheets, like I wanted

Comment: All the code that is shown here operates on a correct sheet, not the active sheet. Are you sure this is the code you are running? Do you have a different version somewhere?

Comment: 2 possible problems: Code works on ActiveWorkbook, not necessarily the workbook that you want. And if the first cell of any column is empty, the code will stop working for that sheet.

Comment: Have just double checked, replaced the macro with above + the ws changes. It doesn't run on the active sheet, it runs on sheet 1, but the column  combiner doesn't progress to the next sheet, only the headings section does. This is why I'm so confused, why would the first loop not reset?

edit: Commented out the headings section just to check, still runs on only sheet1

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this was my own dumb fault, there was a blank cell hidden behind the heading in the start of column B on most of the sheets :(. I need to check the content better before I think it's the code. Apologies for the stupid question!

Comment: At least you learned how to use Worksheet variables... Next step is to learn the `With` statement...